# Custom Inquiry Screen Tab Disappears when Committing Changes

Tags: acumatica, acumatica-kb

I have a custom inquiry screen. You select a customer and a date, and it will display information on different records for the customer. Two tabs are custom tables, one tab is contracts (Leases), and the other tab is all items that are certain non-stock items (deposits) that are paid and refunded.

When I select a customer, the "Leases" tab disappears. When I launch the inquiry from an action on a screen, the data shows. But changing any information on the screen causes the tab to close. All tabs are setup the same. Here is the grid in question:

```
<px:PXTabItem Text="Leases">
    <Template>
        <px:PXGrid ID="gridCustomerLeases" runat="server" DataSourceID="ds" Width="100%" Height="150px" SkinID="Details" AllowAutoHide="False" TabIndex="700">                       
            <Levels>
                <px:PXGridLevel DataMember="CustomerLeases">
                    <RowTemplate>    
                        <px:PXNumberEdit ID="edCLTQty" runat="server" AlreadyLocalized="False" DataField="ContractDetail__Qty"></px:PXNumberEdit>
                        <px:PXSegmentMask ID="edCLTUsrCYLeaseInventoryID" runat="server" DataField="InventoryItem__UsrCYLeaseInventoryID" AllowEdit="true"></px:PXSegmentMask>
                        <px:PXSegmentMask ID="edCLTInventoryItem__InventoryCD" runat="server" DataField="InventoryItem__InventoryCD" AllowEdit="true"></px:PXSegmentMask>
                    </RowTemplate>
                    <Columns>
                        <px:PXGridColumn DataField="InventoryItem__InventoryCD"></px:PXGridColumn>
                        <px:PXGridColumn DataField="InventoryItem__UsrCYLeaseInventoryID"></px:PXGridColumn>
                        <px:PXGridColumn DataField="ContractDetail__Qty" TextAlign="Right" Width="100px"></px:PXGridColumn>
                        <px:PXGridColumn DataField="Contract__ActivationDate" TextAlign="Right" Width="150px"></px:PXGridColumn>
                        <px:PXGridColumn DataField="Contract__ExpireDate" TextAlign="Right" Width="150px"></px:PXGridColumn>
                    </Columns>
                </px:PXGridLevel>
            </Levels>
            <AutoSize Container="Window" Enabled="True" MinHeight="150" />
        </px:PXGrid>
    </Template>
</px:PXTabItem>
```

Here is the view that is attached to the grid

```
public SelectFrom<ContractDetail>
    .InnerJoin<Contract>.On<ContractDetail.contractID.IsEqual<Contract.contractID>>
    .InnerJoin<ContractItem>.On<ContractItem.contractItemID.IsEqual<ContractDetail.contractItemID>>
    .InnerJoin<InventoryItem>.On<InventoryItemExt.usrCYLeaseContractItemID.IsEqual<ContractItem.contractItemID>>
        .Where<Brackets<
                Contract.terminationDate.IsNull
                .Or<Contract.terminationDate.IsGreaterEqual<CustomerCylinderInqFilter.fromDate.FromCurrent>>
                >
        .And<Contract.customerID.IsEqual<CustomerCylinderInqFilter.customerID.FromCurrent>
        .And<Contract.activationDate.IsLessEqual<CustomerCylinderInqFilter.fromDate.FromCurrent>>>>
    .View.ReadOnly
    CustomerLeases;
```

Other grids use similar fields and the same filtered fields but show correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must have the primary view associated with the view on the grid without specifying the DAC in the grid. Because ContractDetail is the primary DAC on the view, ContractDetail__ must be removed. Updating the lines

```
 <px:PXNumberEdit ID="edCLTQty" runat="server" AlreadyLocalized="False" DataField="ContractDetail__Qty"></px:PXNumberEdit>

<px:PXGridColumn DataField="Qty" TextAlign="Right" Width="100px"></px:PXGridColumn>
```

to

```
<px:PXNumberEdit ID="edCLTQty" runat="server" AlreadyLocalized="False" DataField="ContractDetail__Qty"></px:PXNumberEdit>

<px:PXGridColumn DataField="Qty" TextAlign="Right" Width="100px"></px:PXGridColumn>
```

worked.

You may run into this when copying a grid and changing the primary DAC on the view and not removing the DAC prefix on the DataField properties.